# Python code to have batch numbers within a value in a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

I have a dataframe like this

```
  Name  Age
0    U   20
1    U   20
2    U   20
3    U   18
4    I   45
5    I   68
6    I    8
7    D    7
8    D    6
9    I   89
```

and I want to have batch size (say 3) and I want to display another column, which increments the batch number staring from 1 and with batch size being repetitive within a particular column value U, I , D in Name column, after the batch size the batch number should increment by 1(within a particular Name) the output should look like

```
   Name  Age  Batch
0    U   20   1
1    U   20   1
2    U   20   1
3    U   18   2
4    I   45   3
5    I   68   3
6    I    8   3
7    D    7   4
8    D    6   4
9    I   89   5
```

any suggestions or references on how to do this ?

I have this piece of code which kinda does the job, but it does not consider the Name column and then increment.

```
resu['B'] = np.divmod(np.arange(len(resu)),3)[0]+1
```

The output which I got is like this and this is not desired output as it is not considering Name column

```
  index Name  Age  B
0      4    I   45  1
1      5    I   68  1
2      6    I    8  1
3      9    I   89  2
4      0    U   20  2
5      1    U   20  2
6      2    U   20  3
7      3    U   18  3
8      7    D    7  3
9      8    D    6  4
```

Is there any other solution perhaps ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
N = 3

# group successive values
group = df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift()).cumsum()

# restart group every N times
df['Batch'] = (df.groupby(group)
                 .cumcount().mod(N)
                 .eq(0).cumsum()
              )
```

Output:

```
  Name  Age  Batch
0    U   20      1
1    U   20      1
2    U   20      1
3    U   18      2
4    I   45      3
5    I   68      3
6    I    8      3
7    D    7      4
8    D    6      4
9    I   89      5
```